# linear independent functions

Tags: linear-algebra

For two functions to be linearly independent we should have this statement:

> The functions $f_1, \ldots , f_k$ are said to be linearly independent on $I$, if they are not dependent. Equivalently, whenever $\alpha_1, \ldots , \alpha_k \in \mathbb R$ are such that
>   $$\alpha_1 f_1(x) + \alpha_2 f_2(x) + \cdots + \alpha_k f_k(x) = 0, \forall x \in I,$$
>   we have $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \cdots = \alpha_k = 0$.

My question: does the above definition imply that $\alpha_1 f_1(x) + \alpha_2 f_2(x) + \cdots + \alpha_k f_k(x) = f(x)$ in order to be linearly independent?

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: What is $f(x)$ ?

Comment: or say u(x), I meant that, is the linear combination should give you a non constant function unlike the case on dependent where you have the right hand side=0

Answer (score 1):

$\{f_n(x)\}$ is a set of independent functions,

then

$a_1 f_1(x) + a_2f_2(x)+\cdots + a_n f_n(x) = 0 \iff a_1, \cdots, a_n = 0$

What you can say is, $\{f_n(x)\}$ forms a basis for some space, and

$f(x)= a_1 f_1(x) + a_2f_2(x)+\cdots + a_n f_n(x)$ is in the space.